# Editing Jquery Ajax function to call PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal

I have been given our intranet site to add a few features too, but I have very little experience with this kind of coding. (The company we had went out of business. Great). We are running a Drupal site and the following is some custom code to display an orange alert bar on the site (ie: Cookies in the lunch room!)

```
function alert_poll() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({ 
            url: baseUrl + "intranet/alerts/get",
            success: function(data){
                alert_setup(data);
            }, 
            dataType: "html"

        });
    }, 60000); // Polling every 60 seconds

}

// Setup
function alert_setup(data) {
    jQuery(data).find(".views-row").each(function() {
        var alertId = jQuery(this).find(".alert-nid").text();
        var alertMsg = "<span class='alert-label'>** ALERT MESSAGE **</span> <span class='alert-msg'>";
        alertMsg += jQuery(this).find(".alert-msg").html() + "</span>";
        alertMsg += "<a href='#' class='alert-hide'><span>Hide Alert</span></a>";
        if ( !jQuery.cookie("scl-alert-" + alertId) ) {
            // Loop through all on-page alerts to see if this one is currently on the page already
            // if so, don't display
            var displayAlert = true;
            jQuery(".intranet-alert-wrap").each(function() {
                var onpageAlertId = jQuery(this).attr("id");
                if ( onpageAlertId.indexOf("-" + alertId) ) { displayAlert = false; }
            });
            if ( displayAlert ) { inject_alert(alertMsg,alertId); }
        }
    });
    alert_poll(); //Setup the next poll recursively
}

// Drop alert message onto page
function inject_alert(alert_msg,alert_id) {
    jQuery("#zone-content").prepend("<div class='intranet-alert-wrap' id='alert-" + alert_id + "' style='opacity:0;'><div class='intranet-alert'>" + alert_msg + "</div></div>");
    jQuery(".intranet-alert-wrap").stop().animate( { "opacity": 1}, 700, null, function(){});
}
```

Now, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to make it call a PHP function. They want it to make the title bar flash when a new alert is posted. I am trying to use this one: http://heyman.info/2010/sep/30/jquery-title-alert/ It works fine in small testing, but when I try to add it to their custom code I run into the following issues:

1. I can't just add it to 'alertMsg' as that has a dataType of 'html' and just spits the PHP code out as text.
2. I tried using $.post in a few spots and calling a file with the PHP function call, but nothing happened.
3. I tried changing dataType to json, but then the alert just doesn't appear. I think there is more I would have to do here, but I have no idea.
4. I tried to rewrite the body of the drupal node (in a drupal view) to include the PHP call, but the body will not execute PHP as well. I can't use the header or footer since the body is pulled out directly by the code above.

So, is there something obvious I am missing? I just want this call "$.titleAlert('New Alert');" to occur when a new alert is dropped.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Ajax doesn't call PHP functions. It calls a PHP page. That PHP page then calls the function and echos something out.

Comment: Make sure, in your custom module, you have a path 'intranet/alerts/get' declared under hook_menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, and understand correctly what you trying to achieve, you don't need PHP for this. Just make sure that you initialized Jquery Title Alert correclty, and replace this line

```
if ( displayAlert ) { inject_alert(alertMsg,alertId); }
```

with this

```
   if ( displayAlert ) { inject_alert(alertMsg,alertId); $.titleAlert("Your message here!");}
```

if you would like to add the original alert text which appears, change the "Your message here!" to jQuery(this).find(".alert-msg").html()

Comment: I am not a smart man. Of course it's just a Javascript call, not a PHP one. Yikes. I gave this a try but sadly still no go.
The only thing I can think of is that the .js file that has $titleAlert is separate from mine which is calling it, but both are included on the main page where this is all being called from. Do I need to some include the other file into mine (My search says there is no such thing for Javascript).

Comment: Could you tell us the html code from the header, where you include js files? After modifiying the code, the rest of the script works as intenteded?(is the old alert showing?) Please also check, that your jquery is included BEFORE or AFTER TitleAlert. You don't have to include the js file in any other javascript, just make sure, that Jquery is called BEFORE TitleAlert.

Comment: Sorry, I decided to get sick for a few days there. The alert still displays normally with the new code. And it looks like jquery is called before title alert (Jquery is called first out of all the .js files).

Comment: Ok, this is the answer. The TitleAlert code is just not running nicely when inside the site. I threw some other custom code in as you suggested and it worked fine. Thanks for the help. I'll have to debug or find another method to make the title flash.